# Forgot password for external hard drive

Tags: external-hard-drive, passwords, macbook, osx-yosemite

I created a password for WD Elements 2T USB 3.0 external hard drive and I just forgot it. Is there a way to retrieve it or a workaround?

My operating system is OS X Yosemite

Comment: Is the whole drive encrypted, and with What program?

Comment: In editing your question, I removed a phrase that appeared to relate to what you used to set the password but it was grammatically indecipherable.  Please add information on how and where you set the password.

Comment: I was curious, so I looked up the [drive](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=470).  It doesnt look like it has its own encryption, so it must have come from somewhere else.

Comment: From @Captain_WD: Try resetting the password and you may be given a couple of option to retrieve your old one.

Comment: If it was FileVault, hope you created a recovery key, or it's gone - http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202385

Answer (score 0):

If the password has been configured using the WD Smartware software there is no way to retrieve or reset the password and unfortunately no way to recover the data. You can format the HDD and use it.